# UISlider with different minimumTrackTintColor like shown in image preview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uislider

I need to implement change **UISlider minimumTrackColor** with different color according to user selection. Same like shown in image please check.[Check out this example UISlider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfQIk.png)

Comment: Check this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/svcolorpicker

Comment: i have checked lot of third parties but not able to find slider like that i have shown in preview.

Comment: Just make the bar invisible and use a custom UIView under it and pretend that its the bar? Would it be more simple?

Answer (score 0):

you have to setMinimumTrackImage

```
slider.setMinimumTrackImage(UIImage(named: "CLR"), forState: .Normal)
```

CLR.png is [image]